# $.parseJSON not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

$.parseJSON is working great in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari using the code below. However, in Internet Explorer 10, the script fails to yield a valid object.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gahathat/sq6Lb/

And the js code:

```
string = '{"result":"success"}';
$('#json_string').text(string);
item = $.parseJSON(string);
$('#json_result').text(item.result);
```

Is there a workaround for Internet Explorer that would correct this error?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Did you only try it with jsFiddle? The error I get from IE9 is related to iframes.

Comment: I get the same error on my domain as well.

Comment: I see the error `'$' is undefined` in the IE10 console when opening the fiddle.

Comment: And I've tried jQuery 1.9.1 and 2.0.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    var string = '{"result":"success"}';

    $('#json_string').text(string);

    var item = $.parseJSON(string);
    $('#json_result').text(item.result);
});
```

IE has a global object called 'item' which can't be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy trying to figure that out.

Comment: oh my what a problem.just +1

Comment: Man, I would have never thought of that! This just proves what a piece of .... `IE` really is! +1

Comment: @tftd: It's not unusual for browsers to have non-writeable globals, or generally globals that would interfere with other code. So IE wasn't the problem here.

Comment: @CrazyTrain yes I know but this one is quite bizarre, at least for me... :)